# how to insert multiple records from json array in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

learning sequelize ORM, say if the request body has array of values, shown below. when we have multiple users in an array in the request body, how to save it to the database , do we iterate over the array items or is there some kind of function to create multiple records at once?

```
//post('/save', async(request, response) => {
   
    let new_users = request.body.users; 
    
})
```

request body

```
{
  "category": "students", 
   "department" : "engineering", 
  "users" : [ {name: foo, age:12}, {name:bar , age:18}]
}
```

user table columns

```
id
category
department
name
age
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the static `bulkCreate` method of a model to create multiple records at once:

```
await userModel.bulkCreate(users)
```

See [bulkCreate](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-bulkCreate)

Comment: thanks. that worked. one follow up question - for updating in similar fashion, what would be the steps to do it. if you can provide some steps or pseudocode, i can open up a new question if needed.

Comment: You can try the same method

Comment: thanks, so in theory. if i use same function for update, it will just update the ones with new values or create new ones which are not already there

Comment: I suppose it will be something like INSERT .. ON EXISTING UPDATE and it will look on primary key equality. The SQL syntax depends on what DBMS you use